# Addition with generic type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

Hi  I am new to scala and trying to write  addition program in with generic type parameter as shown below

```
object GenericTest extends Application {
  def func1[A](x:A,y:A) :A = x+y    
    println(func1(3,4))
}
```

But this does not work .What mistake i am making .

Comment: You really have to say a lot more about what you're trying to accomplish and what precisely you tried.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485896/how-does-one-write-the-pythagoras-theorem-in-scala.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer .
Randall -I was just trying to play with generic type  and try to use '+' operator over everything i passed to function like string+string ,int+int,double+double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` could be any type in this case. `x + y` means `x.+(y)`, which would only compile if either a) the type `A` had a method `+`, or b) the type `A` was implicitly convertible to a type with a method `+`.

The type `scala.Numeric` provides the ability to write code that abstracts over the numeric system -- it could be called with Double, Int, or even your own exotic numeric system, such as complex numbers.

You can add an implicit parameter to your method of type `Numeric[A]`.

```
object GenericTest extends Application {
  def func1[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]): A = x + y    
}
```

In Scala 2.8, this can be shortened:

```
object GenericTest extends Application {
  def func1[A: Numeric](x: A, y: A): A = x + y    
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot .But i guess i have scala 2.7 on my machine which does not have scala.Numeric Class.

Comment: It is a new addition in 2.8. http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/Numeric.scala.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Scala: How to define “generic” function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters) for what you want.