# Error in Type - Variance - Scala

Tags: scala

```
def test[T<:AnyVal](s:T):T={
s+1
}
```

This is showing this error:

> :11: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : Int(1)
>
> required: String
>          s+1

When T is type of AnyVal why it required String?

Comment: This is a very commonly asked question, phrased slightly differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127934/parametric-type-function-requires-a-string-as-second-parameter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting an error about `String` - although I suspect it's because of other code that you haven't included in this answer - but the code you posted can not work because an `AnyVal` constraint does not suffice if you want to call the `+` method on your `s` parameter.

This is speculation, because you haven't mentioned what exactly you're trying to do, but I imagine it is along the lines of "I want a function that adds 1 to any number, regardless of its type".

If so, `AnyVal` is likely to restrictive (e.g. `BigInt` is not an `AnyVal`). In fact, you don't need such a constraint at all, rather what you need is access to a `Numeric[T]` instance. [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.math.Numeric$) is a type class providing several operators - including `+`.

Usage would look like this (you might have to look into scala's implicits if you haven't already to understand this):

```
def test[T](x: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): T = {
    numeric.plus(x,numeric.one)
}
```

You can still add the `AnyVal` constraint to this if you're sure that you really need it.

Comment: The error is tied to the code posted by the OP. Not all types that extend `AnyVal` have a `+` method (`Boolean` for example), so when the compiler sees `+` on a general `AnyVal`, it tries to implicitly convert `s` to a `String` via `toString`, which every type has. However, it won't also convert `1` to a `String` (as that would be two steps of implicit conversion), so it stops there with a type mismatch.

Comment: @m-z Ah, that makes sense, thanks for that explanation