# Scala operations with Numeric generics

Tags: scala, generics, types, numerics

When I tried to do

```
def subtract[T: Numeric](x: T, y: T) : T = x-y
```

in Scala 2.12, the `-` is not recognized. However, this is basically equivalent to what [Addition with generic type parameter in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096414/addition-with-generic-type-parameter-in-scala) suggests. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is `import Numeric.Implicits._`. This adds that standard infix operators, `-`, `*`, etc., to the current implicit scope. Then everything should work as expected.

Alternatively, you can pull down the implicit and use it directly.

```
def subtract[T: Numeric](x: T, y: T) : T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].minus(x,y)
```