# Are recursive structural types not supported in scala anymore?

Tags: scala

Some people claim that scala is able to deal with recursive structural types if you use the -Yrecursion option of scalac. Nevertheless my minimalistic example does not compile:

```
type Num = {
  def +(n: Num): Num
}
```

Compilation yields:

```
$ scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.8.0.final -- Copyright 2002-2010, LAMP/EPFL
$ scalac -Yrecursion 100 Num.scala 
Num.scala:3: error: recursive method + needs result type
def +(n: Num): Num
               ^
one error found
```

Did this change? Shouldn't the example compile?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201577/scala-how-to-define-a-structural-type-that-refers-to-itself

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Looks like this question raises again and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursive structural types have never been supported. The -Yrecursion option does something unrelated to structural types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and of course for the great work on the Scala IDE.