# Self-referential duck-typing

Tags: scala

I wish to write a function that operates on any value that can be added to other members of its own type (whatever "added" means in context).  The obvious (heh-heh) definition of such a type:

```
type Addable = { def +(a : Addable) : Addable }
```

That gives me an error I don't understand at all: recursive method + needs result type

Why isn't that last `: Addable` the result type?  Why does it think + is recursive anyway?

But I found a more general problem, trying to refer to a type inside its own definition:

```
type T = { def f: T  }
```

But then I had a brain-wave: solve it the way I would in Java!

```
type T[T] = { def f: T  }
```

This compiled!

But now I have two more problems.

First, I have no idea how to use type T.  In particular,

```
def n(a:T) = a.f
```

gives the wholly sensible yet frustrating "type T takes type parameters" error.

Second, attempting to apply this pattern to the original problem

```
type Addable[Addable] = { def +(a : Addable) : Addable }
```

leads to a completely incomprehensible "Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement".  (The actual problem is not that it's "+" -- thank God and Martin, since that would complete mess up my head -- just that it takes an Addable as a parameter.)

So

1. How do I define a duck-type meaning "has a particular function returning a value of the same type"?
2. How do I define a duck-type meaning "has a particular function taking a expression of the same type as a parameter"?

I have a religious-like belief that this problem is solvable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466100/are-recursive-structural-types-not-supported-in-scala-anymore and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201577/scala-how-to-define-a-structural-type-that-refers-to-itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are different Ts.

```
scala> type T[T] = { def f: T  } 
defined type alias T

scala> var x: T[Int] = null
x: T[Int] = null

scala> x = new AnyRef { def f = 5 }
x: T[Int] = $anon$1@44daa9f1
```

When you write:

```
type Addable[Addable] = { def +(a : Addable) : Addable }
```

You have a type Addable which takes a single type parameter, also called Addable.  Here's a similar variation people often confuse themselves with.

```
scala> def f[Int](x: Int) = x * x
<console>:7: error: value * is not a member of type parameter Int
       def f[Int](x: Int) = x * x
                              ^
```

The actual answer to your question is "you can't" but I would hate to shatter your religious-like faith so instead I'll say "structural types work in mysterious ways." If you want to go on a religious mission you might visit here, which explains why you can't.

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/7013

Comment: Die, heretic!  Actually, the article made it clear why you can't do this in a JVM.  I had hoped the Scala would finally solve all my type problems.  Ah, well.  The Quest continues.

Comment: Referring to the linked article: getMethod doesn't require static types. It requires Class objects. Something like 'subject.getClass.getMethod("$plus", Array(subject.getClass))' should work. So I'm still baffeled.