# How define Structural Type that the method return this

Tags: java, scala, structural-typing

I have a number of `Builder`s which comes from library which the source code is auto generated in Java and beyond my control. These `Builder`s are not related one to another, but they have a number of methods which are structurally exactly the same.

```
package a.b

public class Builder {
    public Builder setA(xxx) {}
    public Builder setB(yyy) {}
}

package a.c

public class Builder {
    public Builder setA(xxx) {}
    public Builder setB(yyy) {}
}
```

Using Scala's structural type, how can I return the builder for itself?

```
type StructurallyBuilder = {
    def setA(xxx): StructurallyBuilder
    def setB(yyy): StructurallyBuilder
}
```

When I want to use setA and setB on the `StructurallyBuilder`, the compiler complains that it cannot resolve.

Comment: Probably not so easy:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466100/are-recursive-structural-types-not-supported-in-scala-anymore?lq=1 (and follow the linked questions there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly straightforward, but I believe you can use [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) to achieve that:

```
type StructurallyBuilder[F <: StructurallyBuilder[F]] = {
  def setA(xxx: Int): F
  def setB(yyy: Int): F
}
```

You have to keep this complex signature when defining classes or methods taking those builders. For example:

```
def setA[T <: StructurallyBuilder[T]](
  xxx: Int, 
  builder: StructurallyBuilder[T]
): T = builder.setA(xxx)
```

But it seems you can use those methods normally:

```
val bld: a.c.Builder = setA(10, new a.c.Builder())
```

Comment: Thanks. this is getting closer. I've tried, but I got compiler error when I try to call `setA(10, new a.c.Builder())`. It says "Type mismatch, expected StructurallyBuilder[NotInferedT], actual a.c.Builder". If I put `setA[a.c.Builder]` it expect StructurallyBuilder[a.c.Builder]

Comment: @Wins Hm, this code works for me: https://gist.github.com/kolmar/f9df191b8130f948550b It also works for a Java class with the same signature: `package a.c;
public class Builder {
    public Builder setA(int xxx) { return this; }
    public Builder setB(int yyy) { return this; }
}` Maybe your objects don't corresponf to the signature exactly?

Comment: @Wins Also, it seems Sascha Kolberg is right. You don't even need F-bounded polymorphism. Also see my edit.

Comment: Thanks it works finally. What I missed was in my code is that the parameter in `setA` and `setB` are generic type of another `Builder`.

Comment: Your original answer with F-Bounded polymorphism was correct. Not the later one.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the actual builder a type parameter of the structural type:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scala.language.existentials

type StructurallyBuilder[T <: AnyRef] = AnyRef {
  def setA(xxx): T
  def setB(yyy): T
}
```

Here is a little test I wrote to proof that you can use it to pass around any builder using 'StructurallyBuilder' as a parameter type:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scala.language.existentials

type StructurallyBuilder[T <: AnyRef] = AnyRef {
  def setA(a: Int): T
  def setB(b: String): T
}


class Builder1 {
  var a: Int = _
  var b: String = _

  def setA(a: Int): Builder1 = {
    this.a = a
    this
  }

  def setB(b: String): Builder1 = {
    this.b = b
    this
  }
}

val builder: StructurallyBuilder[_] = new Builder1

val b2 = builder.setA(1)
val b3 = builder.setB("B")

val builder2 = new Builder1

def test(builder: StructurallyBuilder[_]): String = {
  builder.toString
}

val t2 = test(builder2) |-> t2: String = Builder1@7a067558
```

Comment: It is not working as I need. What I need is so that you can do something like `builder.setA(1).setB("B")`

Answer (score 0):

why not use this.type ?

```
type StructurallyBuilder = {
    def setA(x: Int): this.type
    def setB(y: Double): this.type
}
```

Example of such usage:

```
object App
{

  class A {
    def setA(x: Int): this.type = { this }
    def setB(y: Double): this.type = { this }
  }

  type StructurallyBuilder = {
    def setA(x: Int): this.type
    def setB(y: Double): this.type
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit =
  {
    val a = new A()
    if (a.isInstanceOf[StructurallyBuilder]) {
       System.out.println("qqq")
    }
    System.out.println(a)
   }

}
```

Then, trying to run:

```
[info] Running X.App 
qqq
X.App$A@8f59676
```

Comment: Because `this.type` will return the type of the surrounding `StructurallyBuilder`. I don't want to return the class owning `StructurallyBuilder`, I want to return the `StructurallyBuilder` itself