# Scala cast to generic type (for generic numerical function)

Tags: scala, generics, casting, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to implement a generic function that wraps a mathematical Java function. For simplicity, we can assume that the Java function (Java 7) takes one parameter and returns a result, both of type java.lang.Double. Of course, the wrapper function should take a parameter and a result, both of generic but numeric type A. The problem is that I'm not able to cast the result back to type A in the wrapper function. Where/what is the problem?

Note: (I'm a newbie on Scala and used the following reference to solve the problem.)

- I'm using implicit type trait Numeric to enforce that template types are numeric. [How do I implement a generic mathematical function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056452/how-do-i-implement-a-generic-mathematical-function-in-scala)
- I found 'import scala.collection.JavaConversions._' which I do not fully understand, but it seems to me that it's rather for conversion of Java collections and doesn't solve my problem, does it? [Iterating over Java collections in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala)
- As described here, I tried to use Manifest to enforce correct casting (Variant B) which, however, ends up in an exception java.lang.ClassCastException. [Scala asInstanceOf with parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686992/scala-asinstanceof-with-parameterized-types)

### Variant A

```
package test

object mytest {
  def f[A](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = {
    val result = new java.lang.Double(num.toDouble(x))
    result.asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // 'Some code'
  }
}
```

#### 'Some code' A1

```
result val result = f(3)
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at test.mytest$.main(test.scala:10)
    at test.mytest.main(test.scala)
```

#### 'Some code' A2

```
println(f(3))
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

#### 'Some code' A3

```
println(f(3).getClass)
```

Output:

```
int
```

### Variant B

```
package test

object mytest {
  def f[A : Manifest](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = {
    val result = new java.lang.Double(num.toDouble(x))
    manifest[A].erasure.cast(result).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val result = f(3)
  }
}
```

#### Output:

(This is the same also for equivalents of variants A1, A2, and A3, because the exception is now thrown in line 6 of function f.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Double to int
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3176)
    at test.mytest$.f(test.scala:6)
    at test.mytest$.main(test.scala:10)
    at test.mytest.main(test.scala)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't cast `Double` to `Integer` anyway (because it's boxed). `Numeric` just allows you to have a set of mathematical operations  (by `import num._`) on your T - nothing else (you don't need some mediate type for that). A2 works only because println expecting `Any` as a result of `f(3)`, so `T` is automatically inferred to `Any`; `println(f[Int](3))` will never work, `f[Any](3)` will always work.

If you want to implement generic function which operates Doubles (you may need that only if you have operations specific to Double) - you should better return Double. If you can't - you will have to construct the type manually by analizing T:

```
def f[A](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = {
   val result = new java.lang.Double(num.toDouble(x))
   (x match {
       case x: Double => result
       case x: Int => result.toInt
       case x: Float => result.toFloat
       case x: Long => result.toLong
   }).asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

The reason why you can't just do `result.doubleValue.asInstanceOf[A]` here is that A is already boxed. `@specialized` annotation doesn't work for `asInstanceOf` ([type A is still boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213616/why-specialized-annotation-doesnt-work-for-asinstanceof))

UPDATE: actually `@specialized` works:

```
def f[@specialized(Int, Double, Long, Float) A](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = {
   val result = new java.lang.Double(num.toDouble(x)) 

   result.doubleValue.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

But it [doesn't work in Scala REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221875/1809978) - so be careful!

P.S. Manifests are deprecated: use `classTag`/`typeTag` instead

Comment: Isn't there any possibility to enforce casting Double to Integer as in Java, e.g. (int)(1.8) returns 1? Nevertheless, matching the input parameter works for me, but it's little bit like a hack and - from my point of view - it would be nice to have support from the language itself because then Variant B would work, does it? Thanks a lot, for me it works now! :)

Comment: `(1.8).asInstanceOf[Int]` works in scala, but it doesn't work for boxed type (even in Java)

Comment: That's great! The updated solution now uses language features as I would expect a language to work: The solution is now 'truly' generic because the former solution wouldn't have worked (or at least would have need another work around) for a function `def f[A](list: List[A])(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = { ... }` if the list is empty. Thanks! +1 For your updated solution.