# Why @specialized annotation doesn't work for asInstanceOf?

Tags: scala, generics, primitive-types

As far as i understand, `@specialized` annotation should generate some unboxed code for every primitive type i mentioned, but this doesn't work:

```
scala> def aaa[@specialized(Int, Double, Float, Long) T] = (5.0).doubleValue.asInstanceOf[T]
aaa: [T]=> T

scala> aaa[Int]
unrecoverable error (inside interpreter/compiler)
```

This compiles:

```
scala> def aaa[@specialized(Int, Double, Float, Long) T](a: T) = (5.0).doubleValue.asInstanceOf[T]
aaa: [T]=> T

scala> aaa[Int](0)
ClassCastException
```

But it still uses boxed type for asInstanceOf[T]. This obviously works:

```
scala> (5.0).asInstanceOf[Int]
res28: Int = 5
```

UPDATE: 
   Type erasure and answers like that [Writing a generic cast function Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059451/writing-a-generic-cast-function-scala) has nothing to do with my problem. Type erasure just preventing compiler from adding `typecast` byte-code operation for generics, but eventually it will be added - see `ClassCastException` (generated by this op) in my REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is specialized, but under separate compilation (i.e., different lines), the specialized method isn't invoked.

In the following, `b.B.f` works, `c.B.f` is broken.

```
$ scala -Xprint:typer,cleanup

scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package a { object A { def aaa[@specialized(Int) T] = (5.0).doubleValue.asInstanceOf[T] }}
package b { object B { def f = a.A.aaa[Int] }}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <pastie>
package <empty> {
  package a {
    object A extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>(): a.A.type = {
        A.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      def aaa[@specialized(scala.Int) T]: T = scala.this.Predef.double2Double(5.0).doubleValue().asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  };
  package b {
    object B extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>(): b.B.type = {
        B.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      def f: Int = a.A.aaa[Int]
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // <pastie>
package <empty> {
  package a {
    object A extends Object {
      def aaa(): Object = scala.Double.box(scala.this.Predef.double2Double(5.0).doubleValue());
      <specialized> def aaa$mIc$sp(): Int = scala.this.Predef.double2Double(5.0).doubleValue().toInt();
      def <init>(): a.A.type = {
        A.super.<init>();
        ()
      }
    }
  };
  package b {
    object B extends Object {
      def f(): Int = a.A.aaa$mIc$sp();
      def <init>(): b.B.type = {
        B.super.<init>();
        ()
      }
    }
  }
}


scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package c { object B { def f = a.A.aaa[Int] }}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <pastie>
package c {
  object B extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): c.B.type = {
      B.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def f: Int = a.A.aaa[Int]
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // <pastie>
package c {
  object B extends Object {
    def f(): Int = scala.Int.unbox(a.A.aaa());
    def <init>(): c.B.type = {
      B.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so if i call specialized method from another unit - it will not work even with scalac?

Comment: @dk14 the REPL is a resident compiler, so the bug probably originates there. Maybe it doesn't even see the specialized signatures, only the original symbol; that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in Scala REPL - `@specialized` doesn't work there. Compiling `def aaa[@specialized(Int) T] = (5.0).asInstanceOf[T]` with scalac gives:

```
  public <T> T aaa();
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #15                 // double 5.0d
       3: invokestatic  #22                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime
.boxToDouble:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
       6: areturn

  public int aaa$mIc$sp();
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #15                 // double 5.0d
       3: d2i
       4: ireturn
```

`d2i` is exactly what i was expecting. And of course everything works fine with scalac (so I don't need pattern matching for every possible type). So it's just the [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9022) with interpreter.

Comment: For it's solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212776/scala-cast-to-generic-type-for-generic-numerical-function +1

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you just need a more recent compiler? here's what I get with 2.11.2:

```scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_72).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def aaa[@specialized(Int, Double, Float, Long) T] = (5.0).doubleValue.asInstanceOf[T]
aaa: [T]=> T

scala> aaa[Int]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
  ... 33 elided

scala> aaa[Float]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToFloat(BoxesRunTime.java:113)
  ... 33 elided

scala> aaa[Double]
res2: Double = 5.0

scala> 5.0.asInstanceOf[Int]
res3: Int = 5

scala> 5.0.asInstanceOf[Integer]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  ... 33 elided
```

Note that you can directly do `5.0.asInstanceOf[Int]` but not `5.0.asInstanceOf[Integer]`. Also note that the ClassCastException that you get with `aaa[Int]` is referring to java.lang.Integer not Scala's Int class. I suspect what goes on here is that the @specialized annotation is generating a function, `aaa`, that has an "Int" specialization but because of type erasure and boxing is converting that to java.lang.Integer and there is no automatic conversion with `asInstanceOf` between Double and Integer.

Comment: I use latest compiler, but maybe it's REPL specific problem. Anyway the problem is that even with `@specialized` annotation type inside function is still **boxed** (Integer instead of Int). There is no type-erasure in compile-time - more than that every generated function definetely knows about type - so there is no reason to not specify directly Int instead of boxed Integer.