# How to make a generic numeric method in scala 3?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3

I've seen this question answered before, but for scala 2 using `implicit`. However, scala 3 lacks the `implicit` keyword, which leaves me at square one.

So, how would I go about making a generic method like this toy example:

`def add2[T](number: T) = number + 2`

that is, how do I write a method that works equally well for `Double`, `Float`, `Int`, and so on?

Comment: How would you do it in Scala 2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056452/how-do-i-implement-a-generic-mathematical-function-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [new in Scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/new-in-scala3.html) doc mentions - implicits (and their syntax) have been [heavily revised](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/) and now you can achieve this with [`using`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/using-clauses.html) clause:

```scala
def add2[T](number: T)(using num: Numeric[T]): T = {
    import num._
    number + num.fromInt(2)
}
```