# type parameterization of Scala

Tags: scala, types, parameterization

Take a concrete method for instance,

```
def df(f: Float => Float, dt: Float) = (t: Float) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
```

It can be compiled and works. However, when I tried to define it in a generic way,

```
def df[T](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
```

The compiler said,

> "error: type mismatch; found   : T;required: String def df[T](f: T =>
>   T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)".

It seemed like the type T couldn't be added. Then I tried another way,

```
def df[T <: Double](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
```

Again It failed,

```
scala> def df[T <: Double](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: T
       def df[T <: Double](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
                                                             ^
```

Now All my tricks have been exhausted.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first definition:

```
def df[T](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
```

This cannot be because we cannot know if there is a "+" or a "-" method for type T.

Your first definition,

```
def df[T <: Double](f: T => T, dt: T) = (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
```

Short story - cannot extend from `Double` and even if you could the `+` method expects another double, not a `T`.

To do this generically we need a unifying trait that applies to all numeric types and which declares all the numeric operators. Unfortunately, this isn't the case in Scala. But we have the next best thing: type classes (see this question for some info: [What are type classes in Scala useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408861/what-are-type-classes-in-scala-useful-for)). Type classes are implemented in Scala using implicits.

The solution for you would be:

```
def df[T](f: T => T, dt: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = (t: T) => num.minus(f(num.plus(t, dt)), f(t))
```

The method is generic, but it also requires the presence of an object `num` which knows how to do things like `plus`, `minus` and so forth on objects of type `T` and which is passed implicitly. Fortunately, the Scala library provides instances of `Numeric` for all primitive numeric types Int, Double etc so you don't have to.

LATER EDIT:

As Jesper Nordenberg and Régis Jean-Gilles point out you can actually get your initial expression using an import:

```
def df[T](f: T => T, dt: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): (T => T) = {
  import num._
  (t: T) => f(t + dt) - f(t)
}
```

This is achieved using an implicit conversion also.
You can check the source file for `Numeric` for more information about what's going on: [Numeric.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L1)

You should be careful though. This solution may have performance problems if you're doing heavy mathematical computation, mostly because of boxing.

Hope it helps !

Comment: You can also use `import num._` to make operators work on the type T.

Comment: @JesperNordenberg I tried that initially, and I wrote the function like in the question with `+` and `-` but I get an error when adding `dt` - found `T`, expected String. For some reason the implicit conversion is not picked up.

Comment: @JesperNordenberg Also, do you mean `import Numeric._` ? `import num._` doesn't work

Comment: Works for me, `def df[T](f: T => T, dt: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = (t: T) => {import num._; f(t + dt) - f(t)}`. What Scala version are you using?

Comment: Ok, it didn't occur to me that you were referring to the variable `num `. I thought it was a namespace. I updated my answer, thank you !

Comment: You and Jesper answered my question directly and Daniel pointed out a better solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `t + dt` for an arbitrary type `T` because there's no guarantee that `+` exists for `T` -- in fact, most types do not define `+`.

It also doesn't work for `T <: Double` because the method `+` on `Double` subclasses returns a `Double`, and `f` requires that a `T` be passed to it.

Now, you a probably looking for a way to do generic math -- that is, ignore the exact number type passed to you. That isn't easy to do in Scala, particularly if you want performance as well. You can visit [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485896/53013), though there are more efficient approaches nowadays. Look at [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) if you want efficiency.